# TableViewセル番号をindexpathで取得する方法をわかりやすく解説お願いします

Tags: ios, swift

TableViewセル番号をindexpathで取得する方法をわかりやすく解説お願いします。

また、遷移先の情報の入った配列のインデックス番号とセルの行番号を対応させることもお教えください。お願いします。

Answer (score 6):

> TableViewセル番号をindexpathで取得する方法をわかりやすく解説お願いします。

`indexPath.section`と`indexPath.row`を使えば、あなたが「セル番号」と呼んでいるものはおそらく取得できると思います。
セクションが一つしかないなら、`indexPath.row`だけ使えばテーブルの何行目のセルか取得できます。

> 遷移先の情報の入った配列のインデックス番号とセルの行番号を対応さることもお教え下さい。

もしセクションが一つしかないなら、indexPath.rowをそのまま配列のインデックス番号に使えばよいと思います。

---

以上の通り、この質問内容では、当たり前の簡単なことしか回答できません。

もしあなたがTableViewを使ったコーディングをしていて、どうしたらよいかわからなくて困っているなら、もっと具体的に

「こういうことをしたくて、こういう情報を参考にして、こういうコーディングをしたのだけど、なぜかこういう動作になってしまいます。意図通りに動作させるにはどうしたらよいですか?」

と質問した方がよいです。

[良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
も一読することをお勧めします。